# internal compiler error using iOS block format

Tags: objective-c, ios, compiler-construction, objective-c-blocks

I am trying to get use to this format.  However I keep getting odd issues like this...

```
 [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if(granted) {
            mAccounts  = [[accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType] retain];

            if(acctId != nil) {
                mActiveAccount = [[accountStore accountWithIdentifier:acctId] retain];
            }
        }
    }];
```

When I compile I get an error on the last line of the block...

```
internal compiler error: in convert_all_function_calls, at tree-nested.c:1976
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My compiler settings were confused.  I had it set to default which changed per computer.  It needs to be set to 'Apple LLVM 3.0'